# Wordpress Plugin for pastimes/participation in contest

Tags: plugins

I've been searching around for a Form plugin that would allow me built a participation for in my blog so users can win some stuff.

**My needs are:**
- From with custom fields each give away;
- A user can only participate once...
- Option to export the data to excel, csv or something (optional).

I've tried Form Maker it's almost perfect but it allows the user to participate multiple times.

Can someone suggest a plugin to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Your timing isn't great here. Check out this post from a mere 4 hours ago: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if in your searches on [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins) -- did you try these keywords Polls Surveys Competition  [Lester Gamerz WP-Polls](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-polls/) is probably what you need

And wondering  ... did you try searching WordPress.org for the Poll or Survey or Competition in Portugese? or English?

Comment: The don't actually fit my needs, I'm developing one right now. Thanks anyway.